# Keeping track of files on external media

Tags: windows-7, media, metadata

I would like to be able to see all the files which I have backed up to external media (CD, DVD, external drives). At minimum there should be filename and size, more details like thumbnails and other details (bitrate, resolution etc where applicable) would be even better.
I was looking at a program Datacatch but their domain seems have recently expired. I found a [mirror](http://www.brothersoft.com/datacatch-librarian-standard-edition-download-50957.html) with a trial version but it doesn't seem to work on Windows 7.

Does anyone know some software for this purpose which works on Windows 7?

Comment: Well I though I would update this with some more information that I've discovered since posting. I used the trial of Datacatch in an XP VM which seems to be doing what I want, only it's not possible to register it any more since the domain has expired!

Comment: I found some software for MAC which basically does what I want http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/6221/disktracker/ I think it's madness that such a program doesn't exist for Win7. Everyone must have data on external media!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For windows you have [WinCatalog 2012](http://www.wincatalog.com/):

> WinCatalog 2012 indexes discs, files and folders for finding files and data without having to reach for the original CD or DVD. Stop wasting time looking for a tune or movie stored on a hundred’s disc from your growing collection! Simply process your CDs and DVDs with WinCatalog once, and you’ll be able to find any file from the collection in a matter of seconds!

They have a free version called [WinCatalog Light](http://www.wincatalog.com/free.html)

> **WinCatalog Light provides basic cataloguing functionality**
>
> With WinCatalog Light you will never have to waste your time again. Process your CDs or DVDs with WinCatalog Light just once and from this moment on you will be able to find any file in a few seconds without the need to insert the disk in the drive!

---

For the purpose of completeness, here's the comparison:

**WinCatalog Light can:**

- Catalog all disks from on your computer like your hard drives, media collection or data backup: save filenames and tree structure;
- Scan inside ZIP archives;
- Automatically extract mp3 tags and HTML file descriptions;
- Retrieve Audio CD information from freedb.org;
- Manage borrowed disks.

**WinCatalog Light can’t (but WinCatalog 2012 can):**

- Scan inside RAR and 7zip archives;
- Scan inside stored disk images (ISO files);
- Grab EXIF info from digital photographs;
- Keep thumbnail previews for digital photographs and pictures;
- Print contents;
- Search using search operators AND, NOT, etc;
- Use HUGE collection files.